# ROS2 Foxy | Nav2 returns "send_goal failed" error

Tags: ros2, nav2, ros-foxy

I have been following this youtuber "Articulated Robotics" for implementing my autonomous robot. Everything has gone good so far including slam
The only error is nav2 randomly works (1 out of 10) times when I set a 2D Pose Goal.
Most of the time , nav2 returns "send_goal failed" error to me.
Configs are same as the github : https://github.com/joshnewans/articubot_one/blob/main/config/nav2_params.yaml

[image: Terminal + RVIZ image sttatched]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to send the goal pose out of the mapped space boundary?

I guess that can be the reason, why it is not often working...

Or you may have some misconfiguration issues within the local costmap generation or planner server configuration on nav2_params.yaml file ? Some additional log errors/warnings?

Comment: No , my 2D Pose goal is within the mapped environment.

Comment: My configs are same as this github https://github.com/joshnewans/articubot_one/blob/main/config/nav2_params.yaml

Answer (score 0):

It seems it might be a computational issue. Have you allocated enough resources to the virtual machine?

Also try to build you workspace with:
colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release.